# having trouble while connecting python and mysql 2nd time. ie i am impoting same file in line 10, import in 6th line is not working for 2nd time

Tags: python

#name of this file is pass2

```
print("welcome home")
main=input("enter 1 for viewing databases,     enter 2 for editing databases,     3 for paying fees/n")
if main=="1":
    com=input("enter s for students,     enter t for teachers")
    if com=="s":
        import connect
        #importing file for connection with mysql which help me to show table of mysl
        print("press 1 to go home, press 2 to exit")
        #option for starting same work again
        x=int(input("enter your choice:"))
        if x==1:
            import pass2
            #pass2 is this same file which help people to restart this code
        elif x==2:
            exit()
        else:
            print("this choice is no available")
    elif com=="t":
        print("hi teacher")
    else:
        print("invalid entry")
elif main=="2":
    com2=input("enter s for  editing students,     enter t for editing teachers")
    if com2=="s":
        print("edit student")
    elif com2=="t":
        print("edit teacher")
    else:
        print("invalid entry")
else:
    print("invalid entry")
```

#table in mysql is not opening when code is repeated from 10th line and coming back to 6th line of code.6th line imported file help me to show table in mysql after that i have give an import which inport same file(this file)and repeat the procedure .but import file for connection with mysql(6th line) is not working again. plz help

Comment: Look into [creating functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functionshttps://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) to provide reusable units of code.  Rather than trying to repeated import module, import them once and call the function you want as many times as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct solution for the problem you're asking about. It looks like you (will) have a hard time structuring your app this way with growing number of choices. You should split it into smaller functions, each of them dealing with a tiny piece of functionality, and call the functions as needed. Short example:

```
def entry_point():
    """this is entry point of the whole app"""
    main = input("enter 1 for viewing databases,     enter 2 for editing databases,     3 for paying fees/n")
    if main == "1":
        chosen_db = input("enter s for students,     enter t for teachers")
        database_view(chosen_db)
    elif main == "2":
        chosen_db=input("enter s for  editing students,     enter t for editing teachers")
        database_editing(chosen_db)


def database_view(chosen_db):
    """called from entry_point()"""
    if chosen_db == "s":
        print("press 1 to go home, press 2 to exit")
        x=int(input("enter your choice:"))
        if x == 1:
            do_db_mumbo_jumbo()
        elif x==2:
            # calling entry_point() instead of exit() will return you to the start of the app
            # entry_point()
            exit()
        else:
            print("this choice is no available")

...

entry_point()
```